# Swift 3 - Object type 'RealmSwiftObject' is not managed by the Realm exception

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) with Swift 3 in my iOS app. I have the following code

```
//Find all records for the day
func findForToday<T: Object>() -> [T] {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ and date <= %@", DateUtil.dayStart(), DateUtil.dayEnd())
    return getRealm().objects(T.self).filter(predicate).map { $0 }
}
```

where `T` in this context is my realm model class which look like

```
class MyModel : Object {

    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var date = NSDate()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

}
```

I am getting an exception at run time saying

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 
'Object type 'RealmSwiftObject' is not managed by the Realm. If using a custom 
`objectClasses` / `objectTypes` array in your configuration, add `RealmSwiftObject`
to the list of `objectClasses` / `objectTypes`.'
```

Comment: Have any update for this?

Answer (score 4):

The error message is indicating that `T` has been inferred as `Object` rather than `MyModel`, so you will need to adjust the call site to ensure Swift picks the correct type.

Comment: @JaseemAbbas how do you call `findForToday()`? You can specify `MyModel` explicitly like `let todays:[MyModel] = findForToday()` or `let todays = findForToday() as [MyModel]`

Answer (score 3):

The question is pretty old but it looks like you did not add your object to the Realm configuration:

```
var realmOnDisc: Realm? {
        let url = ...URL to your file
        let objectTypes = [MyModel.self, SomeOtherModel.self] 
        let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: url, 
                                         deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded:true, 
                                         objectTypes: objectTypes)

        do {
            let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
            return realm 
        } catch let error {
            log.error("\(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi just resolved such issue. 
In my case if I call your func "findForToday" like

let myArray = MyModel().findForToday() 
and i got same error

but after i specified value type error lost.

let myArray : AnyRealmCollection < MyModel> = MyModel().findForToday()